# Is Not There Any Solution to run Node.JS Code from Chrome?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I wrote a code by using "puppeteer" in Node.Js. I could run the code from CMD of windows and also terminal of PHPStorm. But I need to build a user-interface for my code to let the user select some parameters. I could not prepare a UI by designing an HTML web page because browser (I mean Javascript) could not send and execute Commands to CMD to run my code (written in Node.JS). As you know Chrome and other browsers does not permit to do that for security reasons.
I have 3 questions:

1. Node.JS has a module, named "node-CMD". Could I disable security settings of chrome to allow me to use javascript to run commands by using "node-cmd"?
2. If I could not change the chrome setting, what other solutions are available for running Node.JS code (beside CMD of windows or Terminal of PHPStorm )
3. Does defining a new web server with customized settings on my PC helps my problem? I am asking because of this [comment](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-solution-for-running-a-CMD-line-command-in-JavaScript) by Harry Parker.

regards

Comment: You do it the same way you want to run PHP code from Chrome or any browser - by writing a web server. Nodejs may be javascript but that does not mean the browser can run it. From the browser's point of view nodejs is the same as C++ or Java or PHP or Python

Comment: "*let the user select some parameters*" - why does that need a UI? cli arguments should suffice, no?

Comment: Maybe [`page.exposeFunction()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) can help?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute any commands from browser. You can setup a local server, set up a front end that will allow to you issue some command and send a request to the backend which will then execute given command. Keep in mind that it will execute command on the server, so you cannot execute command on someone else's computer this way.

[Express](https://expressjs.com) is a pretty popular module for creating a server in Node.js.

You can also create an [electron](https://electronjs.org) app if you want to create an app - it's like a browser, but with access to file system and everything else you can access in Node.js

Comment: At first thanks for your answer. You mean if I build a UI by using electron,  i could use "node-cmd" to run my Node.JS codes, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to require() any module you like